# BigTable - Can you store boolean values?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

Is it possible to store boolean values?

I tried storing a True value in BigTable, and got the error message:

> TypeError: True could not be converted to bytes

Looking at the code in [GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/master/core/google/cloud/_helpers.py), the function `_to_bytes` was used, and it throws an error if it cannot be converted to bytes.

Is there a recommended way to store boolean data? Or should I just cast True/False and then remember to convert the values back to Boolean when I retrieve the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot store a Boolean type in BigTable using Python.

This is what the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/overview#data-types) says about the data types that can be stored in BigTable:

> Cloud Bigtable treats all data as raw byte strings for most purposes

So it seems that the best option you have is, as you said, to cast "True/False" as Strings and convert the data back to Boolean when you get it.

Comment: Thanks! Just as what I thought.

Answer (score 2):

This is how HBase converts booleans to bytes in [`Bytes.java`](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/util/Bytes.java):

```
  public static byte [] toBytes(final boolean b) {
    return new byte[] { b ? (byte) -1 : (byte) 0 };
  }
```

The Java `cloud-bigtable-client` encourages that java users use that class for converting primitives to values.  There probably should be a similar class in other libraries to help encourage common conversions.